Name of a diamond-like join-semilattice
Consider the join-semilattice of length $1$ and $n$ minimal elements, for some $n > 0$:

It is similar to the modular lattice $\mathsf{M}_n$, but without the least element. Does this join-semilattice have a name? Is there a preferred way
of referring to it?
Thanks

That's not a join-semilattice, since it has no bottom element. It's the free poset with a top element on the finite set $[n]$, or the opposite of the free DCPO on $[n]$.

@NaïmFavier But join-semilattices don't need to have a bottom...

Yes they do. The join of the empty family is a bottom element.

Oh, I guess there are multiple definitions of semilattices... Wikipedia's definition disagrees with nLab's.

I don't know a single textbook in lattice theory that would agree with nLab on this.

@NaïmFavier Could that be "complete semilattice"? (In which case it would be a lattice anyway.)

No, those are a different thing (also called suplattices or inflattices). The distinction here is whether a join-semilattice should be defined as having joins for every non-empty finite subset, or just every finite subset including the empty one.

@Lorenzo If it worths anything to you, the order-dual of that set is called the flat ordered set on ${a_1,\ldots,a_n}$ in Introduction to Lattices and Order, Davey and Priestley (2nd ed. page 16). For want of a better name, you have a reference to come up with a name starting from there.

@amrsa thank you! I'll look at the reference.

Perhaps one could call it the coflat order ;)

@NaïmFavier I suppose that could be a good idea. Concerning the previous comment, I suppose some people look at semilattices (and perhaps lattices too) as ordered structures not considering them as algebraic structures, and that can lead to that different definition, given it might be more convenient in some contexts.
